# Can't get Email address through Facebook Android SDK

Tags: android, facebook, email

I tried to use below code to get my facebook email address via my app, but return value is null.

I don't know what the reason, but I can get email address using `Graph API explorer`.  Is there anybody know what is wrong with this code?

```
@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

// Request email address

GraphRequest.newMeRequest(

   loginResult.getAccessToken(),new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

   public void onCompleted(JSONObject me, GraphResponse response) {

      Log.d("TEST", response.toString());
      if (response.getError() != null) {
        // handle error
      } else {
        Log.d("TEST", me.toString());
        String email = me.optString("email");
        String id = me.optString("id");
        Log.d("TEST", "Email:" + email);
     }
  }
}).executeAsync();

LoginButton authButton =(LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<>();

permissions.add("public_profile");

permissions.add("email");

authButton.setReadPermissions(permissions);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found the solution, using newMeRequest method fetches fields from a user object. In the case, I need email as an additional fields, so added “email” into fields parameter and request specific fields:

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest( 

//...

});

Bundle parameters = new Bundle();

parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email");

request.setParameters(parameters);

request.executeAsync();
```

Comment: I couldn't fetch email except this trick,,,
email working, why downvote,,,

Answer (score 1):

Set the read permissions before you make the request and do it in the following way:

```
 GraphRequestAsyncTask request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject user, GraphResponse response) {
                        final Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();

                        if ((user != null) && (profile != null)) {

                            accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

                            if (accessToken.getDeclinedPermissions().isEmpty()) {


                                try {
                                   String email = user.get("email").toString();
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }


                            }


                        }
                    }
                }).executeAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set permissions before the request.

Anywayt the `email` field may return null for two reasons:

1 - user didn't confirm the email address during the registration

2 - users could be signed up in Facebook using a phone number instead of email.

Documentation says:

> Note, even if you request the email permission it is not guaranteed
>   you will get an email address. For example, if someone signed up for
>   Facebook with a phone number instead of an email address, the email
>   field may be empty.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Those are not in my case. It seemed to me some app permissions was not configured properly, my current app is development  mode, in facebook developer webpage, the status show the email permission in Login Permissions  was "not available to all user because the app is not live" .